# Why does this error appear in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

This is my code that is supposed to create a verification command (the prefix is "!" and I use the load_extension feature):

```
import asyncio
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import time
from discord.utils import get

class Commands(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, bot: commands.Bot):
        self.bot = bot
    @commands.command(name="verify")
    async def verify(self, ctx: commands.Context, user: discord.Member):
        message = await ctx.send(f"Type `verify`to get access to the server \nYou have 60sek left.")
        check = lambda m: m.auhtor == ctx.message.author and m.channel == ctx.channel
        try:
            confirm = await self.bot.wait_for("message", check=check, timeout=60)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await message.delete()
            return

        if confirm.content == "verify":
            await ctx.message.delete()
            await message.delete()
            await user.add_roles(861641636312514630)

def setup(bot: commands.Bot):
    bot.add_cog(Commands(bot))
```

but as soon as I type !verify in a channel this error comes up:

```
Ignoring exception in command verify:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Laurenz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Laurenz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 855, in invoke
    await self.prepare(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Laurenz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 789, in prepare
    await self._parse_arguments(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Laurenz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 697, in _parse_arguments
    transformed = await self.transform(ctx, param)
  File "C:\Users\Laurenz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 542, in transform
    raise MissingRequiredArgument(param)
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: user is a required argument that is missing.
```

why does it say that "user" is missing and what do I have to change?

Answer (score 1):

The command you have has a required argument: `user`.
When someone uses the verify command without the `user` argument it results in this error:

```py
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: user is a required argument that is missing.
```

Here's that part of your command fixed:

```py
@commands.command(name="verify")
async def verify(self, ctx: commands.Context):
    message = await ctx.send(f"Type `verify` to get access to the server\nYou have 60s left.")
    check = lambda m: m.author == ctx.message.author and m.channel == ctx.channel
    try:
        confirm = await self.bot.wait_for("message", check=check, timeout=60)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        return await message.delete()
        
    if confirm.content == "verify":
        await ctx.message.delete()
        await message.delete()
        await ctx.author.add_roles(861641636312514630)
```

Comment: it kind of helped but it gave me another error: https://ibb.co/BVnMvzP (i had to add a link to an image of the error because its too long for an answer)
and it didnt delete the "verify" message you have to send to actually verify it only deleted the command and the bots message

Comment: @Ruko this is another error in your code. [Read here how `Member.add_roles()` works](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=add_roles#discord.Member.add_roles) and [read here how `Guild.get_role` works](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.get_role)